# Añadir una nueva columna a tabla

Tags: php, html, json, pdf, sql

Estoy realizando un formato `PDF` donde todos los item que esten por debajo de `reorder_level (minimo)` y con `status = 1`, son los que se mostraran en el documento.

Este es el codigo donde estoy haciendo una estructura `json`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <?php echo'<title>Inventory To Reorder</title>';?>
</head>

<body onload="window.print()">
  <?php echo '<img src="http://localhost/WareHouse/assets/img/logo.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height:6%; width:25%; margin-top:40px; margin-left:40px;"/>';?>
    <?php  echo '<center style="margin-top:120px; font-size:14pt;"><strong>Inventory To Reorder<strong></center>';?>
  <?php  echo '<label><center>____________________________________________________________________________</center></label><br>';?>
<?php

require_once('apis/connection.php');
    if(isset($_GET['status']))
    {
      $status = $_GET["status"];
      //Trae todos los item que esten por debajo de su minimo en stock.
      $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();
      $query = 'SELECT i.description_item,i.quantity,u.name_unit,i.reorder_Level,i.target_Stock,l.name_location,i.commentt,io.quantity_s
      FROM inventory_list AS i
      INNER JOIN unit_mesurement AS u ON id_unit = fkUnit
      INNER JOIN locatiON AS l on id_location = fkLocation
      INNER JOIN inventory_output as io on id_output = fkInventory
      WHERE i.quantity <= reorder_Level AND i.status = 1';

      $result = $connection->executeQuery($query,array($status));
      if ($result > 0) {
  ?>
  <center>
            <table class="table table-striped xd" border="1px;">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Description</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Quantity</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Name Unit</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Reorder Level</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Target Stock</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Area</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Comment</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php
                $arraycount=count($result);
                $i=0;
                $total=0;
                while ($i < $arraycount)
                {
                  ?>
                            <tr>
                             <td><center><?php echo $result[$i]['description_item']; ?></td>
                             <td><p style="color:red;" ><?php echo $result[$i]['quantity']; ?></p></td>
                             <td><?php echo $result[$i]['name_unit']; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $result[$i]['reorder_Level']; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $result[$i]['target_Stock']; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $result[$i]['name_location']; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $result[$i]['commentt']; ?></center></td>
                            </tr>
                <?php $i++;
              }
                ?>
            </table><br><br>
  </center>
      <?php
      }
    }
  ?>
</body>
```

Este es el resultado final, esto funciona perfectamente. No tengo ningun problema.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi `query`, estoy trayendo tambien `quantity_s(cantidad de salida)` y lo que necesito es poner if de rangos de:

```
  if ((quantity_s >=  100)&&(quantity_s <= 200)) {
    $text = "Entre 100 y 200";

     if ((quantity_s >=  300)&&(quantity_s <= 500)) {
      $text = "Entre 300 y 500";
    }
  }
```

Necesito por ejemplo en mi `quantity_s` tengo `1500` se encuentra dentro del rango anterior, y en una nueva columna `Usage`, poner el letrero anterior.

```
       <th style="width: 3%;">Quantity</th>
        <th style="width: 3%;">Usage</th>
        <th style="width: 3%;">Name Unit</th>
        <th style="width: 3%;">Reorder Level</th>
        <th style="width: 3%;">Target Stock</th>
        <th style="width: 3%;">Area</th>
        <th style="width: 3%;">Comment</th>
```

Donde asigno los valores lo estoy poniendo asi:

```
 <td><?php echo $result[$i][$text]; ?></td>
```

Me manda el siguiente error, cuando genero el `PDF`.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: text in
C:\xampp\htdocs\WareHouse\reporte.php
on line 67
Notice: Undefined index: in
C:\xampp\htdocs\WareHouse\reporte.php
on line 67
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:
utilizamos un switch true y le damos valores a comparar puedes usar if pero se me hace mas legible asi!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <?php echo'<title>Inventory To Reorder</title>';?>
    </head>

    <body onload="window.print()">
      <?php echo '<img src="http://localhost/WareHouse/assets/img/logo.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height:6%; width:25%; margin-top:40px; margin-left:40px;"/>';?>
        <?php  echo '<center style="margin-top:120px; font-size:14pt;"><strong>Inventory To Reorder<strong></center>';?>
      <?php  echo '<label><center>____________________________________________________________________________</center></label><br>';?>
    <?php

    require_once('apis/connection.php');
        if(isset($_GET['status']))
        {
          $status = $_GET["status"];
          //Trae todos los item que esten por debajo de su minimo en stock.
          $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();
          $query = 'SELECT i.description_item,i.quantity,u.name_unit,i.reorder_Level,i.target_Stock,l.name_location,i.commentt,io.quantity_s
          FROM inventory_list AS i
          INNER JOIN unit_mesurement AS u ON id_unit = fkUnit
          INNER JOIN locatiON AS l on id_location = fkLocation
          INNER JOIN inventory_output as io on id_output = fkInventory
          WHERE i.quantity <= reorder_Level AND i.status = 1';

          $result = $connection->executeQuery($query,array($status));
          if ($result > 0) {
      ?>
      <center>
                <table class="table table-striped xd" border="1px;">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 3%;">Description</th>
                        <th style="width: 3%;">Quantity S</th>
                        <th style="width: 3%;">Quantity</th>
                        <th style="width: 3%;">Name Unit</th>
                        <th style="width: 3%;">Reorder Level</th>
                        <th style="width: 3%;">Target Stock</th>
                        <th style="width: 3%;">Area</th>
                        <th style="width: 3%;">Comment</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <?php
                    $arraycount=count($result);
                    $i=0;
                    $total=0;
                    while ($i < $arraycount)
                    {
                      ?>
                                <tr>
                                 <td><center><?php echo $result[$i]['description_item']; ?></td>
<td><p style="color:red;" >
    <?php 
    $qs = $result[$i]['quantity_S'];
    switch (true) {
       case ($qs >= 1000 && $qs <= 2000) :
         echo "{$qs} se encuentra dentro del rango anterior de 1000 a 2000";
        break;

        case ($qs >= 2001 && $qs <= 3000) :
         echo "{$qs} se encuentra dentro del rango anterior de 2001 a 3000";
        break;

        case ($qs >= 3001 && $qs <= 4000) :
         echo "{$qs} se encuentra dentro del rango anterior de 3001 a 4000";
        break;
    }
     ?>
    </p></td>
                                 <td><p style="color:red;" ><?php echo $result[$i]['quantity']; ?></p></td>
                                 <td><?php echo $result[$i]['name_unit']; ?></td>
                                 <td><?php echo $result[$i]['reorder_Level']; ?></td>
                                 <td><?php echo $result[$i]['target_Stock']; ?></td>
                                 <td><?php echo $result[$i]['name_location']; ?></td>
                                 <td><?php echo $result[$i]['commentt']; ?></center></td>
                                </tr>
                    <?php $i++;
                  }
                    ?>
                </table><br><br>
      </center>
          <?php
          }
        }
      ?>
    </body>
```

Comment: Gracias, tu respuesta me ayudo a mi problema, solo cambie el || por un  &&. Todo funciona de acuerdo a la quantity_s.

Comment: hahahhaaha sorry no me fije xD